# AS3 Timer class

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I need to create a timer using as3 timer class or some other class. And every 10 second i want to do some alert or trace something. Timer wont stop at any time. And every 10 second we can do some stuff.

Comment: @J_A_X you asked him for code and before he could give it you closed the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class of course would be the Timer class.
Here is a simple example to get you started.

```
package 
{
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class TimerExample extends Sprite 
{
    public function TimerExample() 
    {
        var timer:Timer = new Timer(10000);
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
        timer.start();
    }

    public function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void 
   {
        trace("timerHandler: " + event);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't be simpler:

```
var t:Timer = new Timer(10000);
t.addEventListener("timer", doSomething);
t.start();

function doSomething(event:*):void {
    trace("something");
}
```

Comment: Bad formatting, no scope specified on your variable and function, using string based event instead of `TimerEvent.TIMER` and not specifying event type on your function.  Simple problem yes, but you just added a lot of extra problems yourself.

Comment: You don't know his code so there's no point wrapping the code in a pretty package/class if he's just going to copy and paste stuff. I'm just showing the minimal code. I'm using a string instead of TimerEvent.TIMER because it's shorter, as clear, and doesn't require an import statement (yes you could argue that I could mistype "timer" but well if you can't type "timer" correctly, there are probably other huge issues in your code). I'm using "*" as the event type because the event is not used. The code might not fit your idea of what's right but it has no problem whatsoever.

Comment: That is true that it would compile, but at what cost?  Code like this is the reason why I still see a lot of issues in systems because of "developers" that can't be bothered.  Code quality is very low in this example, no matter what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: In my experience, systems fail or are hard to maintain mostly because of architectural errors or poor programming skills, not so much because of syntax choices.

Comment: And yet, the question totally deserved such an answer.

Comment: +1 for being a minimalist. There is no reason for your down vote. The OP asked for a timer and got one.

Comment: I understand where J_A_X is coming from. It's a bad habit and easy to fall into. For experienced programmers its one thing to run a quick prototype, for beginners ... its a headache waiting to happen.